# Laravel HomeController not found

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I got a little problem with my Laravel 5.4 applicaiton.

I use the standard HomeController which is created with `php artisan make:auth`

**HomeController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index($params = "")
    {
        $param = $params;
        return view('main', ['testvar' => $param]);
    }
}
```

Now I want to pass a variable to the Controller in the routing I call:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/main', function(){
    return App::make('HomeController')->index("Something");
});
```

But I get an error when I call the URL "main":

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 719:
>
> Class HomeController does not exist
>
> in Container.php line 719
>
> at ReflectionClass->__construct('HomeController') in Container.php line 719
>
> at Container->build('HomeController') in Container.php line 598
>
> at Container->resolve('HomeController') in Container.php line 567
>
> at Container->make('HomeController') in Application.php line 708
>
> at Application->make('HomeController') in Facade.php line 221
>
> at Facade::__callStatic('make', array('HomeController')) in web.php line 25
> at Router->{closure}() in Route.php line 189

Can someone please show me where I made the mistake?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't you forget to prefix your class name with the namespace?

Try:

```
Route::get('/main', function(){
    return App::make('App\Http\Controllers\HomeController')->index('Something');
});
```